# Cassandra row read/update optimization

Tags: cassandra

I have a use case where a large number of rows in Cassandra are being frequently read and updated, where the write/read ratio is slightly above 1. Also, writes in most cases replace all the values in a row. I'm wondering how to optimize for such use case. Usually, leveled compaction is suggested, but since the whole row essentially gets reinserted, size tiered compaction *seems* a better way. Am I right? Are there some specific optimizations that can also be done in such case?

Comment: why do you think you need an optimization? do you have any specific problem already?

Comment: Leveled compaction is good fit for that yes. Size tiered is only better if you never read the data or your disks are absolute garbage and cant handle the extra write load (~ 5-10mb/s)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you're trying to *optimize*. Leveled compaction and Size-tiered compaction have different upsides and downsides in your use case, and which one is better for you may depend on the specifics of your use-case or hardware:

Leveled Compaction Strategy (LCS), which other people seem to be warmly recommending in their responses, has a benefit of wasting the least amount disk disk **space** - around 10% - to store old data which has already been overwritten. On the other hand, the biggest downside of LCS is that it uses a lot more disk I/O - rewriting the same data over and over to maintain the low space usage. Since your use case is heavy in writes (as many as half of the requests are write), this extra write I/O may become a big problem.

Size-Tiered Compaction Strategy (STCS) will need to do less I/O work per write, but at the same time waste more disk space: By default you can have as many as 4 versions (!) of each row stored in 4 different sstables before compaction kicks in and gets rid of the older copies. You can significantly reduce this waste by setting `min_threshold=2` instead of the default `4`, but it will still not come close to the space-optimality of leveled compaction. Cassandra's Size-Tiered compaction implementation also has the problem that during compaction it needs both input and output files to exist at the same time - leading to the often-quoted need to always leave half of the disk space free (ScyllaDB has a solution to this last problem, but Apache Cassandra does not).

To summarize, with STCS you will need more disk **space**, while with LCS you will need more disk **bandwidth**. Which one is a worse problem for you depends on your hardware and how close you are to being bottlenecked by the disk's bandwidth, the amount of diskspace, or neither.

For more details about these issues, you can check out a blog post I wrote on [Size-tiered compaction and space amplification problem](https://www.scylladb.com/2018/01/17/compaction-series-space-amplification/), and another one on [Leveled Compaction and its write-amplification problem](https://www.scylladb.com/2018/01/31/compaction-series-leveled-compaction/).

Comment: STCS with frequent rewrites has an additional negative effect of having a copy of the partition in almost every sstable, so as the data set grows reads get very slow and expensive. The data in the largest sstables will contain obsolete data and always be included in the reads. With LCS you have 1 sstable per level that can possibly have the partition (excluding L0)

Comment: My main concern is not really about space, but about efficiency. STC has an advantage of keeping the most recent data always in the last copy, in this particular case, while avoiding excessive IO. Will other copies be read anyway?

Comment: Chris, you're right about the read amplification, and I forgot to mention it. But his use case is 50/50 on reads and writes, LCS does more write I/O, and STCS does more read I/O so overall it's not clear which is worse. I think if min_threshold=2 in STCS, it will be better than LCS (in amount of I/O), but you should definitely verify this with your use case.

Comment: @NadavHar'El so even when the new version of a row is totally in a new sstable, old copies will still be read? If so, that is a strong negative with total row replacements.

Comment: This is a good question, and I don't know the answer (you may want to ask on the Cassandra mailing list or start a new question specifically on this). Theoretically Cassandra could indeed read sstables in timestamp recency order, and the selected row was already fully read, there is no need to continue reading from sstables which are known to only contain older timestamps. I vaguely remember Cassandra having such an optimization, but not sure.